# What is the meaning of “barinyas”

Tags: meaning

Quotation from [*Anarchism and Other Essays*](http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=SJZbe0qxLboC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Anarchism%20and%20Other%20Essays&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ei=5D6PUdPoAcSllQW0zYCICw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA)

She was outraged by the terrible treatment to which the female servants were subjected: maltreated and exploited by their **BARINYAS**, they fell to the tender mercies of the regimental officers, who regarded them as their natural sexual prey

Comment: This version is easier for English readers to search: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2162/2162-h/2162-h.htm – and it looks like this may be a foreign word, as the essays put loanwords and titles in all caps.

Answer (score 3):

This is the Russian word [барыня](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BD%D1%8F), meaning “lady” (a *boyar*'s wife), possibly cognate to English *baroness.*